# is it possible to integrate kafka consumer in the xamrin Android application

Tags: android, spring-boot, xamarin, apache-kafka, xamarin.android

I am having a kafka producer which is running in Spring boot i would like to integrate to andriod mobile(xamarin) to push some notifications without using FCM because google is restricted in china. So,i have successfully configured the producer below are my questions i have.

1. writing the consumer in spring and provide as a REST Service, in this case, need to maintain kafka as a separate server so that the consumer can run Independently.
2. In Case of writing the consumer in the android side and after receiving from the topic we can convert to an notification? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't **send** push notifications, so you'll need GCM (or whatever alternative works in your location).

Kafka clients *pull* information from the brokers, and doing so over a mobile connection is **not** recommended, so therefore having Kafka wouldn't really be useful in that scenario of the REST server, as it would only be a backend-only service.